# Playing browser videos in external players

Tags: python, video, browser

I'm new to the coding world and I need some help with playing videos from websites in external players.

What i'm trying to do is write python code to retrieve the video links from a website so I can play them later in vlc player. (if it's even possible)

I've used programs like urlsnooper, replay media catcher, wire shark to retrieve the embedded video links but all the links found by the programs don't work.

Ex. If I take http://www.ctvnews.ca/video?playlistId=1.2725950

I get 
http://ams-vp4.9c9media.com/hds-vod/ae/2016-01-07/2E77A2F7AAAFA655/CTVNews-967035-CFCF0107_FIREUPDATE-Adaptive_01.mp4.f4m

It just keeps on duplicating. Anyone have any ideas.

**Edited 7:45pm EST**

I think I have an idea on a solution to my problem. Just want to check with you guys if someone knows anything.

I'm thinking maybe I can write code with selenium. Basically open a web browser with the link to the video and full screen the video.

So my question is, can selenium interact with adobe flash player? if not, is there something else that works for this idea.

Comment: http://docs.livestreamer.io/

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 for the fast reply. :)

Comment: Not working for this site :(

Answer (score 0):

The links you are retrieving from these tools aren't to the source media, but to pieces and optimized versions for the shockwave video player on the page. There also appears to be content validators to prevent just such use of their videos.

Comment: Is there a way to get around the content validators?

Comment: It depends on how much you want any individual piece of content and their implementation. If the validators are unique to every web session, then you're better off automating a screen-recording tool. If there's a simple validator for all content, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into screen-recording. Sounds a lot better from what I came up with yesterday. I managed to write a basic script to full screen the video link from chrome browser but it's not reliable. do you mind taking a look and see if there was a better way.

Comment: import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size (1366, 768)
driver.get("http://www.ctvnews.ca/video?playlistId=1.2728350")

pyautogui.size()
(1000, 1080)
width, height = pyautogui.size()

pyautogui.keyDown('down')
pyautogui.keyDown('down')
pyautogui.keyDown('down')

pyautogui.moveTo(1148, 670,)

time.sleep(25)
      
pyautogui.click(1149, 670)

time.sleep(20)

input = "What do you want to do now"

choice 1 = "Return to main" "close video window" (alt+F4 keyborad input)
choice 2 = "Play next video"

Comment: I apoligize in advance for not formatting the code to view properly.